# Paginate Links in Wp Query Shortcode

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

so been looking around for this answer, but no go -- basically i have a WP Query that is incased in a shortcode.. I have set up the paginate links function which outputs it on the page. However, the page url does not change when clicked (href does show the correct url -- /page/2) I know it is something with the main Query when executed in a shortcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'paged' => $paged

);

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

// Put default query object in a temp variable
$tmp_query = $wp_query;
// Now wipe it out completely
$wp_query = null;
// Re-populate the global with our custom query
$wp_query = $the_query;

?>




    <div class="row">
<?php  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  $i=0; ?>



    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        $sphere = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'testimonial_profession', true);
        if ($i == 2) {
        $i = 0;
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
    }

    ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="testimonial_inner_wrapper">
                                <?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                <h4 class="testimonials-inner-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <?php if(!empty($sphere)): ?>
                                    <div class="testimonial_sphere"><?php echo($sphere); ?></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="short_separator"></div>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="media-left media-top">
                                        <div class="testimonial-media-unit">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('img-69-69', array('class'=>'testimonial-media-unit-rounded')); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4 class="testimonials-inner-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <?php if(!empty($sphere)): ?>
                                            <div class="testimonial_sphere"><?php echo($sphere); ?></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <div class="short_separator"></div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                        <div class="testimonial_inner_content" style="color:#aaaaaa"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>
                        </div> <!-- inner wrapper -->
                    </div>


    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
</div><div class="poNav">
     <?php

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );

    $wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?></div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php
    $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; 
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `$args` in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$args` variable would be helpful.

As I can see, you are creating custom WP_QUERY, so `get_query_var('paged')` isn't related to your `$the_query = new WP_QUERY`, but to `global $wp_query`.

Possible solution:
declare `global $paged` and add it to `$args = array( /* your args here*/, 'paged' => $paged );`, also change your `get_query_var('paged')` to `$paged`

Comment: added the $args to the code

Comment: just replace `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;` to `global $paged;`. If it won't work it's more possible that you have written something wrong in `paginate_links()` function.